# then the value of $ \frac{1-\vert a \vert^2}{\pi} \int_{\gamma} \frac{\vert dz \vert}{\vert z+a \vert^2} $.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $a\in  \mathbb{C}$ with $\vert a \vert <1$ , then the value of

$$ \frac{1-\vert a \vert^2}{\pi} \int_{\gamma} \frac{\vert dz \vert}{\vert z+a \vert^2} $$

where $\gamma$ is the simple closed curve with $\vert z \vert=1$, taken with the positive orientation.

I tried but I cant manipulate the denominator, I used $z \bar z =\vert z \vert^2$, Please help.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hint: Write $|z+a|^2 = (z+a)(\bar{z}+\bar{a}) = (z+a)(z^{-1}+\bar{a})$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee, thanks, ur hint help

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024356/complex-integration-frac1-a2-pi-int-l-fracdzza2?rq=1